# php using curl and preg_match_all

Tags: php, curl, preg-match-all

I feel like I am missing something.  I am using the following code to pull some numbers from a table.  As simple as it looks, I cannot seem to get anything to print.  I am placing my code and an example of the table below.  Please help me find my error.  I want it to print out only the numbers in each cell.

```
//gets the site
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.org');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch); 

//parse the data
preg_match_all('/<td align=right>(\d+?)</td>/', $response, $matches2);

//prints the parsed data
print_r($matches2[0]);
```

Here is a sample of the table.

```
<center><table border=1><tr><th align=left>Address</th><th width=50>0</th><th width=50>1</th><th width=50>2</th><th width=50>3</th><th width=50>4</th><th width=50>5</th><th width=50>6</th><th width=50>7</th><th width=50>8</th><th width=50>9</th></tr><tr><td>N7:0</td>
<td align=right>1</td>
<td align=right>1</td>
<td align=right>1</td>
<td align=right>99</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
</tr><tr><td>N7:10</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>7300</td>
<td align=right>16400</td>
<td align=right>3300</td>
<td align=right>2200</td>
<td align=right>6100</td>
<td align=right>28000</td>
<td align=right>18000</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
</tr></table></center><hr width=25% align=center>
```

Comment: I would highly suggest using `DOMDocument` or similar DOM-based manipulation to get at the table data rather than regex.  Your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP-Error-Reporting should have given you a hint.
I strongly advice to set error_reporting to E_ALL and display_errors to "on" during development.This would have given you a hint, as to why you don't get any results:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 't'
```

So you should add an escape to the slash inside your regex, because, you use it as delimiter.

```
preg_match_all('/<td align=right>(\d+?)<\/td>/', $response, $matches2);
```

As always, I would suggest, using another delimiter and thus keep your regex more readable. I normally choose "~". This would look like:

```
    preg_match_all('~<td align=right>(\d+?)</td>~', $response, $matches2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/<td align=right>(\d+?(\.\d+)?)<\/td>/', $response, $matches2);

print_r($matches2[1]);
```

Notice the forward slash in the closing TD tag is now escaped.

Comment: I see that this is showing the entire match.  I only want to output the number.  What do I need to do different for that?

Comment: The first element of $matches2 is the whole match. From there the remaining elements are the captures. (In this case there's only one capture.)

Comment: I see that this code will pick up regular numbers.  What do I have to change if the table shows a decimal number?  ie.  8.4563

Comment: Response updated for decimals.

Comment: I am getting the whole numbers, but not the decimal  numbers to match.  The number should look like 8.822430.