# php curl using regular expression preg_match_all issue

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am using the follow code in my php to pull data from a table.  The output of the matches is the entire match ie.

```
<td align=right>1</td>
<td align=right>1</td> etc...
```

What I would like to do is just return the number in the table.  How can change my preg_match_all to do that?

```
//gets the site
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.org');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch); 

//parse the data
preg_match_all('/<td align=right>(\d+?)<\/td>/', $response, $matches2);

//prints the parsed data
print_r($matches2[0]);.
```

Here is a sample of the table.

```
<center><table border=1><tr><th align=left>Address</th><th width=50>0</th><th width=50>1</th><th width=50>2</th><th width=50>3</th><th width=50>4</th><th width=50>5</th><th width=50>6</th><th width=50>7</th><th width=50>8</th><th width=50>9</th></tr><tr><td>N7:0</td>
<td align=right>1</td>
<td align=right>1</td>
<td align=right>1</td>
<td align=right>99</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
</tr><tr><td>N7:10</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>7300</td>
<td align=right>16400</td>
<td align=right>3300</td>
<td align=right>2200</td>
<td align=right>6100</td>
<td align=right>28000</td>
<td align=right>18000</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
<td align=right>0</td>
</tr></table></center><hr width=25% align=center>
```

Comment: Use `$matches2[1]` instead of `$matches2[0]` to get the number within each table cell.

Comment: As @Jack said, use `[1]` -- isn't that why you put the capture group in the regexp?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312196/php-using-curl-and-preg-match-all ?

Comment: The question was different because it was related to the match returning.... but the previous question was answered while I was creating this one.